# How to scrape reviews when all the data needed is not formatted as text?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Im trying to scrape reviews for university research. The code that I have prints out most of the information that I need, but I need to also find the rating and the userId.

This is some of my code here.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


s = requests.Session()

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36',
           'Referer': "http://www.imdb.com/"}


url = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082158/reviews?ref_=tt_urv'
r = s.get(url).content
page = s.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
soup.prettify()

cj = s.cookies
requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(cj)

s.post(url, headers=headers)

for i in soup('style'):
    i.decompose()
for s in soup('script'):
    s.decompose()
for t in soup('table'):
    t.decompose()
for ip in soup('input'):
    ip.decompose()

important = soup.find("div", id='tn15content')

print(important.text)
```

This returns most of the information I need in a printout like this.

OUTPUT (Just showing this one review, prints out all of them on the page)

```
120 out of 141 people found the following review useful:

This is one of the Oscar best pictures that actually deserved the honor.

Author:
gachronicled from USA
18 February 2001



I happened to be flipping channels today and saw this was on.  Since it
had
been several years since I last saw it I clicked it on, but didn't mean to
stay.  As it happened, I found this film to be just as gripping now as it
was before.  My own kids started watching it, too, and enjoyed it - which
was even more satisfying for me considering the kind of current junk
they're
used to.  No, this is not an action-packed thriller, nor are there juicy
love scenes between Abrahams and his actress girlfriend.  There is no
"colorful" language to speak of; no politically correct agenda underlying
its tale of a Cambridge Jew and Scottish Christian.This is a story about what drives people internally - what pushes them to
excel or at least to make the attempt to do so.  It is a story about
personal and societal values, loyalty, faith, desire to be accepted in
society and healthy competition without the utter selfishness that
characterizes so much of the athletic endeavors of our day.  Certainly the
characters are not alike in their motivation, but the end result is the
same
as far as their accomplishments.My early adolescent son (whose favorite movies are all of the Star Wars
movies and The Matrix) couldn't stop asking questions throughout the movie
he was so hooked.  It was a great educational opportunity as well as
entertainment.  If you've never seen this film or it's been a long time, I
recommend it unabashedly, regardless of the labels many have tried to give
it for being slow-paced or causing boredom.  In addition to the great
story
- based on real people and events - the photography and the music are
fabulous and moving.  It's no mistake that this movie has been spoofed and
otherwise stolen from in the last twenty years - it's an unforgettable
movie
and in my opinion its bashers are those who hate Oscar winners on
principle
or who don't like the philosophies espoused by its protagonists.
```

However, I also need the userID and rating given to each movie.

The userID is contained in each a href element like so ...

```
<a href="/user/ur0511587/">
```

The rating is contained in each img element like this where the rating is equal to the "10/10" in the alt attribute.

```
<img width="102" height="12" alt="10/10" src="http://i.media-imdb.com/images/showtimes/100.gif">
```

Any tips on how I would be able to scrape both of these items in addition to the output that is easily scraped by printing "important.text" without just printing "important"? Im hesitant to just print "important" because it would be quite messy with all of the tags and other unnecessary stuff. Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *css selectors*, `a[href^=/user/ur]` will find all the anchors that have a href starting with `/user/ur`, `img[alt*=/10]` will find all the *img* tags that have an *alt* attribute with the value `"some_number/10"`:

```
user_ids = [a["href"].split("ur")[1].rstrip("/") for a in important.select("a[href^=/user/ur]")]
ratings = [img["alt"] for img in important.select("img[alt*=/10]")]

print(user_ids, ratings)
```

The problem now is that there is not every review has a rating and just finding every *a[href^=/user/ur]* will give us more than we want ,so to deal with that we can find the specific *div* that contains the anchor and the review(if present) by finding the *small tag* that contains the text *review useful:*, then calling *.parent* to select the div.

```
import re
important = soup.find("div", id='tn15content')

for small in important.find_all("small", text=re.compile("review useful:")):
    div = small.parent
    user_id = div.select_one("a[href^=/user/ur]")["href"].split("ur")[1].rstrip("/")
    rating = div.select_one("img[alt*=/10]")
    print(user_id, rating["alt"] if rating else "N/A")
```

Now we get:

```
('0511587', '10/10')
('0209436', '9/10')
('1318093', 'N/A')
('0556711', '10/10')
('0075285', '9/10')
('0059151', '10/10')
('4445210', '9/10')
('0813687', 'N/A')
('0033913', '10/10')
('0819028', 'N/A')
```

You are also doing a lot more work to get the source than you need to, all you need is a single get request, the full code needed would be:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082158/reviews?ref_=tt_urv'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "lxml")


important = soup.find("div", id='tn15content')

for small in important.find_all("small", text=re.compile("review useful:")):
    div = small.parent
    user_id = div.select_one("a[href^=/user/ur]")["href"].split("ur")[1].rstrip("/")
    rating = div.select_one("img[alt*=/10]")
    print(user_id, rating["alt"] if rating else "N/A")
```

To get the review text, just find the next p after the div:

```
for small in important.find_all("small", text=re.compile("review useful:")):
    div = small.parent
    user_id = div.select_one("a[href^=/user/ur]")["href"].split("ur")[1].rstrip("/")
    rating = div.select_one("img[alt*=/10]")
    print(user_id, rating["alt"] if rating else "N/A")
    print(div.find_next("p").text.strip())
```

That will give you output like:

```
('0511587', '10/10')
I happened to be flipping channels today and saw this was on.  Since it
had
been several years since I last saw it I clicked it on, but didn't mean to
stay.  As it happened, I found this film to be just as gripping now as it
was before.  My own kids started watching it, too, and enjoyed it - which
was even more satisfying for me considering the kind of current junk
they're
used to.  No, this is not an action-packed thriller, nor are there juicy
love scenes between Abrahams and his actress girlfriend.  There is no
"colorful" language to speak of; no politically correct agenda underlying
its tale of a Cambridge Jew and Scottish Christian.This is a story about what drives people internally - what pushes them to
excel or at least to make the attempt to do so.  It is a story about
personal and societal values, loyalty, faith, desire to be accepted in
society and healthy competition without the utter selfishness that
characterizes so much of the athletic endeavors of our day.  Certainly the
characters are not alike in their motivation, but the end result is the
same
as far as their accomplishments.My early adolescent son (whose favorite movies are all of the Star Wars
movies and The Matrix) couldn't stop asking questions throughout the movie
he was so hooked.  It was a great educational opportunity as well as
entertainment.  If you've never seen this film or it's been a long time, I
recommend it unabashedly, regardless of the labels many have tried to give
it for being slow-paced or causing boredom.  In addition to the great
story
- based on real people and events - the photography and the music are
fabulous and moving.  It's no mistake that this movie has been spoofed and
otherwise stolen from in the last twenty years - it's an unforgettable
movie
and in my opinion its bashers are those who hate Oscar winners on
principle
or who don't like the philosophies espoused by its protagonists.
```

Comment: Padraic, thats great thanks. It helps a lot. Just wondering for the future, would it be possible to do that so that I would be able to print the ratings and userId's next to its accompanying review and information I printed earlier?

Comment: @user6326823, no worries,  see the edit in relation to the associated review text

Comment: No worries, normally we would use id's , class names etc.. but on this particular site there are not really any that are useful or reliable to get what we need